# TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

my Service.js

```
appnService.factory('LocationService', function(){

var currentLocation = {
    latitude:"",
    longitude:""
}

 return {
   GetLocation : function(){
     return navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
            currentLocation.latitude = pos.coords.latitude;
            currentLocation.longitude= pos.coords.longitude;
          return currentLocation;
     });
   }
 };

});
```

my controller

```
appne.controller('NewObservationCtrl',function($scope,$state,LocationService) {     
LocationService.GetLocation().then(function(data){
console.log(data);
});
});
```

But im getting the error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined in controller

Please help

Comment: maybe because [navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) return nothing

Comment: CurrentLocation has the values Object {latitude: 11.9384867, longitude: 79.8352657}

Comment: look that piece of your code `return navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`

Comment: It might not return a promise, can you `console.log(LocationService.GetLocation())` in your controller.

Comment: It is showing undefined ashish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function() {})` return `undefined`. If you want promise you must resolve deferred object with position value

```
.factory('LocationService', function ($q) {

var currentLocation = {
    latitude: "",
    longitude: ""
}

return {
    GetLocation: function () {
        var d = $q.defer();
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
            currentLocation.latitude = pos.coords.latitude;
            currentLocation.longitude = pos.coords.longitude;
            d.resolve(currentLocation);
        });
        return d.promise
    }
};

});
```

Comment: Thnku Krzysztof Safjanowski..It is working fine... But the data which im getting in controller is saying undefined..actually it is taking some time to get the location data in service. but before that my controller is getting executing..can u tell how to handle this

Comment: @KarthikYeruva - fixed, sorry for answer without checking it

Comment: What you want to do with response? Are you allowing to read your geolocation by browser?

Comment: Yes Krzysztof Safjanowski..i didnt seen your edited answer..now i applied your changes..they are working.